# How to bind a function to an Action from Qt menubar?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm using Python3 and PyQt5, make my widgets and windows in Qt Designer. What is more, I do not generate .py files from a .ui. I simply load it using next code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('UI/Qt/source/MainWindow.ui', self)
```

So, I wanted to know, how do I bind menu bar actions to functions.

Is there any way I can do something like this?

```
self.getActionByName("actionTest_Action").connect(self.do_something)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to use findChild when using loadUi since this method adds the object to the attributes of the class using the objectName as a name, for example in this particular case a cleaner code than [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65499931/6622587) is:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('UI/Qt/source/MainWindow.ui', self)

        self.actionTest_Action.triggered.connect(self.test)

    def test(self):
        print("Test")
```

Comment: Thank you! That also does work. Very bad IDE cannot recognize it though..

Answer (score 1):

So, answering my own question..

One way to do this, is to find an action by using FindChild(QAction, "ActionName") function, and then bind a function using connect() function

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('UI/Qt/source/MainWindow.ui', self)

        action = self.findChild(QAction, "actionTest_Action")
        action.triggered.connect(self.test)

    def test(self):
        print("Test")
```